# Expected number of Tests (Need to confirm my solution)

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value

I'm doing this problem from "The Probability Tutoring Book" by Carol Ash.

> The probability that a well is polluted is .1. Suppose 100 wells are tested as follows.
>
> Divide the wells into 5 groups of 20. For each group, water samples from each of the 20 wells are pooled and one test is performed. If a test is negative, all the wells in that group are safe. If a test is positive each one of the 20 wells must be tested.
>
> Find the expected number of tests we need to perform under this procedure.

I'm going to attempt this problem by using the Law of Total Expectation.

$$E[X] = E[E[X|i\text{ groups positive}]] = \sum_{i = 0}^{5}{E[X|i\text{ groups positive}]}{P(i\text{ groups positive})}$$

Now let's find all the $P(i\text{ groups positive})$ and $E[X|i\text{ groups positive}]$
$$E[X|0\text{ groups positive}] = 5 \text{ and}$$
$$E[X|i\text{ groups positive}] = 20i \text{ for i = 1, 2, ..., 5}$$

$$P(i\text{ groups positive}) = {5 \choose i}{\left({1 - .99^{20}}\right)^i}\left(.99^{20}\right)^{5-i}$$

If we want exactly $i$ of them to be polluted then then the probability of that would be ${5 \choose i}{\left({1 - .99^{20}}\right)^i}\left(.99^{20}\right)^{5-i}$. Any feedback on the probability here would be greatly appreciated :)

So now that I've found all the terms in the sum for E[X] I can just add them together.

Is this solution correct? If not, constructive feedback is happily welcome!

EDIT: I've made edits to the above problem thanks to be brilliant people in the comments right below. However, now I'm having a different problem.

So I computed the above summation via wolframalpha and got an expected number of tests $\approx 20$, but the answer at the back of the book claims that the answer should be $\approx 83$

Comment: The probability that a group tests positive is $1 - (0.9)^{20}$. Even though all the groups are equally likely to test positive, it does not mean that their sum of probabilities has to be $1$. What you did is something like this: If there are $5$ fair coins, the probability of a coin will show head when tossed is $1/5$, which is incorrect. This is because the random nature is just governed by the coin (or in this case the group) and not the number of instances of such coins (or groups).

Comment: I don't see where you use the fact that $P(S)=0.1$

Comment: @sudeep5221 Where does .9 come from? Do you mean (0.99)^20?

Comment: @BigBear The probability that a well is polluted is $0.1$ and hence the probability that it is clean is $0.9$. I have used this to compute the probability that at least one of the $20$ wells is polluted.

Comment: @sudeep5221 OH! Oops totally thought P(polluted) was .01... don't know why I thought that. Thanks!

Comment: Also I think you would double count if you use this approach. I would calculate it as follows. $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[X] = 5 \left( 1 + 20 \cdot(1 - (0.9)^{20}) \right)$, which is simply $5$ times the expected number of tests for each group.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Correct me if I'm wrong but if I find the expectation on conditions that partition that entire sample space then that would find everything once, right? Where am I double counting?

Comment: @BigBear Yeah sorry my bad. You won't be double counting through your method. But it certainly seems rather cumbersome to evaluate the expected value that way.

Comment: @sudeep5221 So the book provides that the answer should be about 83, while I'm getting approximately 20..., any thoughts why?

Comment: Maybe because you took the probability as $0.99$ instead of $0.9$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Oh dude... you're brilliant! I wish there were a "applause" emoji I could use here. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BigBear No problem! :)